# How to test for the class of a variable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to check if the elements of an Array are a subclass of UILabel in Swift:

```
import UIKit

var u1 = UILabel()
u1.text="hello"
var u2 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20))
var u3 = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, 200, 80))

var myArray = [u1, u2, u3]

var onlyUILabels = myArray.filter({"what to put here?"})
```

Without bridging to objective-c.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Swift has the `is` operator to test the type of a value:

```
var onlyUILabels = myArray.filter { $0 is UILabel }
```

As a side note, this will still produce an `Array<UIView>`, not `Array<UILabel>`. As of the Swift 2 beta series, you can use flatMap for this:

```
var onlyUILabels = myArray.flatMap { $0 as? UILabel }
```

Previously (Swift 1), you could cast, which works but feels a bit ugly.

```
var onlyUILabels = myArray.filter { $0 is UILabel } as! Array<UILabel>
```

Or else you need some way to build a list of just the labels. I don't see anything standard, though. Maybe something like:

```
extension Array {
    func mapOptional<U>(f: (T -> U?)) -> Array<U> {
        var result = Array<U>()
        for original in self {
            let transformed: U? = f(original)
            if let transformed = transformed {
                result.append(transformed)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
var onlyUILabels = myArray.mapOptional { $0 as? UILabel }
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but I can't log the count of `onlyUILabels` in the playground with var `onlyUILabels.count` do u have an idea why is that?

Comment: Perhaps you can ask a new question? If I add `onlyUILabels.count` as a new line at the end of my playground, I get 1. (But sometimes it crashes instead; there might just be some instability in this beta.)

Answer (score 7):

In Swift you should do the `is` keyword if you are wondering about the according class. In the `filter`-closure you can use `$0` to specify the first parameter.

### Sample

```
var (a,b,c,d) = ("String", 42, 10.0, "secondString")
let myArray: Array<Any> = [a,b,c,d]
var onlyStrings = myArray.filter({ return $0 is String })
onlyStrings // ["String", "secondString"]
```

Comment: _trailing closure syntax_ is useful as `myArray.filter { $0 is String }`

Comment: You are right, I've just copied the example from above

Answer (score 3):

Without getting to the object.class( ) nirvana, in Swift, we can still use the Objective-C Runtime to get some useful information about the object´s class as follows (and not exactly bridging to Objective-C):

```
let objectClass: AnyClass = object_getClass(object) as AnyClass
let objectClassName =  NSStringFromClass(objectClass)
println("Class = \(objectClassName)")
```

Note that we get the "MyProject." or (sometimes) the "Swift." prefix, depending if you refer to your own classes or Swift classes:

```
UILabel // UILabel    
Swift._NSSwiftArrayImpl //Swift Array
MyProject.Customer_Customer_   //for a CoreData class named Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You may compare classes using the following in swift:

```
 return object.dynamicType == otherObject.dynamicType
```

dynamicType will return an instance of Class which you may compare