# How to determine Self class in swift initializers

Tags: swift

Within a convenience initializer of a parent class, how do I determine the current class before calling `self.init()`?

```
public class Vehicle {

    public convenience init( withDictionary rawData: [String:AnyObject] ) {

        // how do I determine whether this is a Car here?

        self.init()

    }

}

public class Car: Vehicle {

}

public class Bike: Vehicle {

}
```

Comment: Use the "is" keyword: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24097894/2351432

Comment: You shouldn't I beleive. Superclass should know nothing about it's subclasses.

Comment: @MattLogan "self is Car" throws an error because using `self` is not allowed before init(). I found that `self.dynamicType` is, though. See my answer below.

Comment: @ShadowOf There are valid use cases. For example, you want to perform certain generic task that applies to all Vehicles, but let each specific subclass implement this task for its purposes. In most cases you can do this after calling `self.init()`, but in my case I had to find a way to call it before `self.init()` and static methods were the answer.

Comment: @thatjuan Ah yeah of course. Not sure this is possible then. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like using `self.dynamicType` is allowed:

```
public class Vehicle {

    public convenience init( withDictionary rawData: [String:AnyObject] ) {

        let myType = self.dynamicType

        print( "This is a \(myType)" )

        self.init()

    }

}

public class Car: Vehicle {

}

public class Bike: Vehicle {

}

let car = Car( withDictionary: ["key":"value"] )

// prints "This is a Car"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "is" operator to determine the kind of class.

```
public class Vehicle 
{

  public convenience init( withDictionary rawData: [String:AnyObject] ) 
  {

    self.init()

    if self is Car
    {
      print("It's a car")
    }
    else if self is Bike
    {
      print("It's a bike")
    }

  }
}
```

But, you can also do your initialisation inside the  init function of Car or Bike.

Comment: It was important that the code can run before the self.init() call. Also `self.dynamic` allows for the type to be used without having to enumerate every possible subclass in order to determine which one it is.